# Which Riemannian manifolds admit a finite dimensional transitive Lie group action?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

This is a basically an adjusted version of my earlier question about how to define a convolution algebra on a general Riemannian manifold.  The motivation for asking such a question of course comes from the observation that if G is a group and X is a manifold and the action of G on X is transitive, then the pullback from each point in X to its orbit is faithful.  This then cuts out an ideal in the convolution algebra on G which would (hopefully) correspond to some type of general convolution on X (and that would be pretty handy to have for many obvious reasons).

My intuition is that for 2D surfaces (which is the case I am most interested in right now), the group is going to be something like $PSL(2) / \pi(X)$ with the action obtained by the pushforward of the action of $PSL(2)$ on $RP^2$ by the universal covering of $RP^2 / \pi(X)$.  Of course, trying to work all of this out via quotient relations is an enormous pain in the neck, so it would be nice to maybe avoid some headaches and instead try to find maybe some standard references for this sort of thing (if they exist at all).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At least in the compact case, there's a topological obstruction.  In a 2005 paper, Mostow proved that a compact manifold that admits a transitive Lie group action must have nonnegative Euler characteristic.  Here's the reference:

[MR2174096](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2174096) (2007e:22015)
Mostow, G. D.
A structure theorem for homogeneous spaces.
Geom. Dedicata 114 (2005), 87--102.

Of course, even if X admits a transitive Lie group action, most Riemannian metrics on X will not be homogeneous.  (You didn't say whether you wanted actions by isometries, but I assume that's what you're interested in, because otherwise the Riemannian structure on X is irrelevant.)  In the 2D case, the only compact, connected, homogeneous Riemann surfaces are the sphere, $RP^2$, the torus (and maybe the Klein bottle?)*, all with constant-curvature metrics.  In general, the group has to be compact, because the isometry group of a compact Riemannian manifold is itself compact.

*EDIT 3: An earlier paper by Mostow constructed a transitive group action on the Klein bottle, but I doubt that this action preserves a Riemannian metric.  It's a complicated construction, so I haven't had a chance to work through it in detail, but here's the reference:

Mostow, G.D., [The Extensibility of Local Lie Groups of Transformations and Groups on Surfaces](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969437). Ann. Math., Second Series, (52) No. 3 (1950), 606-636.

I don't know what's known in the noncompact case.

Comment: Thanks!  Though I guess this kind of blows the idea out of the water.  It would be nice if the theorem went in the opposite direction so that surfaces embeddable in R3 could be equipped with a group action, but I suppose that it is the best one can do.  Anyway, I will read through the paper and maybe try to understand a bit better what is going on.

Comment: Jack -- how can a Lie group act transitively on the Klein bottle?

Comment: algori -- Oops, I guess that's a mistake.  I don't see how to construct a transitive action on the Klein bottle, though offhand I don't see how to prove that it's impossible either. 

Comment: algori -- I take that back.  Apparently there is a transitive action on the Klein bottle.  See my latest edit above.

Comment: Jack -- I think the argument is as follows (for actions of compact groups): if a transitive action exists, it preserves a metric, which is of constant curvature, which is 0. Any isometry of the plane which is not a translation has a fixed point, so any fixed point free action of a group on the plane must be by translations and if the action is discrete and the quotient is compact, it must be a torus.

Comment: algori -- I see a couple of problems with this argument.  First, a transitive action by a noncompact group need not preserve a metric -- for example, consider the (conformal) action of the Möbius group on the sphere.  Second, not every non-translational isometry of the plane has a fixed point.  For example, there are glide reflections such as (x,y) -> (-x,y+1).

Comment: Jack -- yes, of course, this argument shows that the plane can't cover the Klein bottle, which is definitely false! So I guess the argument should be as follows: take a transitive action by isometries of a flat metric and take the group of all lifts of all transformations to the plane. The resulting group will contain all translations, but translations do not descend to the Klein bottle.

Comment: ..and yes, this works only for compact groups. So my guess is that Mostow's example (btw thanks for the reference!) is non-compact.

Comment: I believe that a typical nilmanifold, such as upper 3x3 real matrices modulo upper 3x3 integer matrices, will be compact but have a noncompact isometry group.

Comment: David -- I don't know what the full isometry group is in that case, but here's a proof that the isometry group of a compact Riemannian manifold M must be compact.  Let G be the isometry group and H the isotropy group of a point, so G/H is diffeomorphic to M.  Then the action of an element of H is determined by what it does to tangent vectors at the base point, so H injects into the group of orthogonal transformations of the tangent space at the base point, and thus it's compact.  Since H and G/H are both compact, it follows that G is compact. 

Comment: Thanks.  Is the image of H in that orthogonal group really closed?  It's not obvious to me.

Comment: David -- here is an alternative proof of the compactness of the isometry group. The set of isometries of a compact metric space $X$ is homeomorphic to the set of the graphs of isometries, regarded as a subset of the set $2_c^X$ of all nonempty compact subsets of $X\times X$ equipped with the Gromov-Hausdorff metric. The space $2_c^X$ is compact, so one can take the closure of the set of isometries there. Now the limit of a sequence of graphs of isometries is again a graph of an isometry. This shows in particular that all stabilizers of points are compact.

Comment: David -- Good question -- my proof certainly doesn't make it obvious that the image of $H$ is closed.  Here's a sketch of an argument that it is.  Suppose $\phi$ is a limit point in the image of $H$ in the group of orthogonal transformations of the tangent space at the base point $p$, and let $\Phi_i$ be elements of $H$ such that $d\Phi_i \to \phi$.  Define a map $X\to X$ by sending each geodesic $\gamma$ starting at $p$ to the geodesic with initial tangent vector $\phi(\gamma'(0))$.  This map is a uniform limit of isometries, and thus is an isometry itself.

Comment: Algori: I don't know anything about the GH topology, but being the graph of a function doesn't look like a closed condition to me.  Are the accumulation points of the sets $\{(x,sin(kx))\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ really still graphs?  Jack: this gets you an isometry of a neighborhood of $p$, but is the map still well-defined where different geodesics run into each other?

Comment: David -- see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance for the definition and some properties. Also, the limit of a sequence of the graphs of functions is in general not the graph of a function, but I think the limit of a sequence of the graphs of isometries is.

Comment: David -- yes, the limit map is well-defined.  It's uniquely defined away from the cut locus by the recipe I gave; in there it's a uniform limit of isometries and thus an isometry.  Then use the fact that an isometry defined on a dense open subset extends by continuity to an isometry on the whole space.  To prove uniformity, use comparison theory to show that if $\gamma$ and $\tilde\gamma$ are geodesics starting at the same point, the distance between $\gamma(t)$ and $\tilde\gamma(t)$ can be estimated in terms of $t$, $|\gamma'(0)-\tilde\gamma'(0)|$, and bounds on the curvature.

Comment: I see!  I also see now that the nilmanifold example is misleading: a nilpotent group has a right-invariant metric but not a bi-invariant metric.  So G does not act on G/H through isometries.

Comment: The isometry group can never be transitive on the Klein bottle, in fact no compact group can be transitive. That is because a transitive action by a compact group $ G $ on the manifold $ M $ implies the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group of $ M $ must be finite, but that is false for the Klein bottle. There is a nice transitive action of the Euclidean group of the plane $ E^2 $ on the Klein bottle. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316503/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-klein-bottle-as-a-linear-group-orbit

Answer (score 7):

If a connected **complete (edit)** Riemannian manifold $M$ has an isometric transitive effective action of a Lie group $G$, then the manifold is diffeomorphic to $G/G_x$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of a point $x\in M$. Since $G_x$ preserves the metric at $T_x M$, then $G_x$ must be compact (the action $G_x:T_xM\to T_xM$ is faithful by considering the exponential map). Thus, one obtains all such manifolds by quotienting a Lie group by a compact subgroup.
Another viewpoint is that the Lie algebra of the identity component of $G$ gives rise to a subspace of the [Killing vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) on $M$. When you restrict the vector space of Killing fields to a point $x$, then the image should map onto the tangent space $T_x M$. I think this is necessary and sufficient.

An interesting example is the [Poincare dodecahedral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_dodecahedral_space#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere). In fact, one can decide which elliptic 3-manifolds are homogeneous, as the ones of the form $SU(2)/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma \leq SU(2)$ is finite.

Comment: You said: "...the image should map onto the tangent space $T_xM$. I think this is necessary and sufficient."

  Necessary, yes, but not sufficient unless $M$ is complete and simply connected. To see that completeness is necessary, just think of an open interval. As for simply connected, the Killing fields will lift to Killing fields on the universal cover, and by a monodromy argument, the local diffeos that they generate will fit together to define global isometries of the universal cover. But, unless these isometries "preserve" the deck translations, these isometries need not descend to $M$.

Comment: @ Palais: You're right about the completeness - I suppose I was implicitly assuming this. As for the simple connectivity, I don't believe this is necessary (at least for compact manifolds). A smooth vector field on a compact manifold is complete, and therefore generates a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms. If the vector field is a Killing field with respect to a Riemannian metric, then the diffeomorphims are Riemannian isometries. I'll have to think about the non-compact case (i.e. whether Killing fields are complete) - maybe this is what you're getting at? 

Comment: Thanks, Agol. Yes, Killing vector fields on a complete manifold  generate one parameter groups of isometries. So what I said was incorrect. What I MEANT to say is that M is LOCALLY homogeneous iff the LOCAL Killing fields near each point x span $TM_x$. Since these lift to the universal cover, the same is true there, where the condition implies (by a monodromy argument) that the isometry group G is transitive. Whether M itself is homogeneous depends on whether the subgroup of G that commutes with deck transformations is transitive. (For an examples, think of the Klein Bottle and Lens spaces.) 

Answer (score 7):

I think that one of the nicest results in this direction may be the one in Ambrose and Singer's paper "On homogeneous Riemannian manifolds". They give a local NASC for a complete Riemannian manifold to be homogeneous. There is a follow-up book by Tricerri and van Hecke called Homogeneous structures on Riemannian manifolds.